# How do I transfer apk file to another device

Tags: android, apk

I am new to android.I am having a need of sending an apk file to a client in abroad.I would like to email the apk file. But how could the client install this apk in his device? Please suggest me the ways for transferring an apk file!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to be answered. Where you want to send the file what is your target destination email, ftp etc. Please update your question.

Comment: he can copy the apk file to his device through usb and install it

Comment: Is there any way where I can upload my apk file in google play store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can send it to a gmail account which automatically detects it's an apk. and will ask the user if he wants to install it on phone. That's the best way to do it through the network.

else you will need to send it in an email, and he will download it to his PC and upload it to his phone by cable or bluetooth. then click on it and it will ask to install.

I think the first way is less hard work.

Answer (score 1):

@Mahe: You can not upload the apk file in google play store directly. You need separate account in google store. 
You can read the play store account procedure ::http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html

Better way send apk file in mail.Once downloaded he can directly install by clicking on it.